# Lack of Indentation on Template Literals in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm traversing through Angular2 tutorial with Typescript on Atom and apparently it doesn't indent template literals.

Is it a bug or a feature/standard of the language?

Comment: Could you provide an example? And when you say: "it doesn't indent" ... are you referring to the tutorial or to Atom?

Comment: @DeborahK or atom. But may be something to do with the plugin or the language. You can try to indent the code in this page https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2

Comment: I would not think that indenting would have anything to do with the language but rather the editor. And the page you linked to has lots of different code examples, so I'm not sure which one you are referencing.

Comment: @DeborahK the html part

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a bug or a feature/standard of the language

Its simply a feature that isn't implemented.